# Rails many-to-many relations and nested forms: associate with object if it already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having an issue with several many-to-many relations in my Rails project. It can be illustrated with an example:

Say I have the models `Person` and `PhoneNumber`, joined by `PersonPhoneNumber`. The relation is many-to-many because people can have more than one phone number, and more than one person can be reached at the same phone number (in a case such as a help desk).

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_phone_numbers
  has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :person_phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_phone_numbers
  has_many :people, :through => :person_phone_numbers
  validates :number, :uniqueness => true
end

class PersonPhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :phone_number
end
```

I have a person form that lets me create/update people's contact information. I use it to assign the number `555-555-1212` to Bob. If a `PhoneNumber` object with that number doesn't exist, I want it to be created (as in the standard `accepts_nested_attributes_for` behavior). But if it does exist, I want to just create a `PersonPhoneNumber` object to associate Bob with that `PhoneNumber`.

How can I accomplish this most elegantly? I tried putting a `before_validation` hook in `PersonPhoneNumber` to look for a matching `PhoneNumber` and set `phone_number_id`, but this caused really bizarre behavior (including making my Rails server crash with the message `Illegal instruction: 4`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists? method to check for existence first, like this:

```
@person.phone_numbers.build(number: "555-555-1212") unless @person.phone_numbers.exists(number: "555-555-1212")
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
PhoneNumber.find_or_create(person_id: @person.id, number: "555-555-1212")
```

Comment: This is a many-to-many relation, not a `has_many/belongs_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel the Rails documentation says this:

A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model, with no intervening model.

What is the difference?